# Is Captain Kirk forgetting all the other races in the Federation?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-beyond, federation

[image]

In Star Trek Beyond, Krall monologues to Captain Kirk on how the unity of the Federation is not a strength, but is instead a weakness. Captain Kirk musters a response something like this, "I think you are underestimating humanity." But, was Krall even talking about humanity? Or, was he talking about the peaceful, melting pot of the Federation? Was Captain Kirk referring to something else?

Comment: It's just the Universal Translator screwing with your understanding of the actual dialog. Don't worry. Everything is fine and dandy and James definitely didn't forget about all the naked green ladies.

Comment: What's the point of dropping these killer one-liners to bad guys if the translator wont deliver them with precision? "You can't handle the truth!" >> "For your own safety, I better not say." :) Good one.

Comment: @Mario - I see we've resorted to the "Universal Translator" explanation (I just did it myself for the imperial vs metric question).  I believe we've created our won trope!

Comment: s/b "own trope"

Answer (score 7):

The word "humanity" - however derived from the word "human" - is a property not only of humans, but of other intelligent species, such as those in the Federation. It's a concept which was named "humanity" by humans in the time when humans knew only of humans as an intelligent species. Somewhen someone may find a word which is more descriptive, or we can extend the meaning of "human", like the meaning of the word "man" was extended from "adult male" to "person" in many languages.

Comment: Relevant quote from Star Trek VI. Spock: "We both both know that I am not human." Kirk: "You know what Spock? Everybody's human!"

Comment: Re: "the meaning of the word 'man' was extended from 'adult male' to 'person' in many languages": Can you give an example of such a language? In English, the exact opposite happened ("man" originally meant "person", but eventually came to mean specifically "adult male"), so I'd be interested to hear about a language where the reverse happened. :-)

Answer (score 6):

I took the statement to only mean the human species, on purpose. Krall's biggest point is that he wants humans (as a race) to endure strife in order to grow (what doesn't kill you ...). He believes that the human race has lost its teeth by joining/founding the Federation of Planets and that's why he wants to bring pain and suffering to a Federation Starbase.

In the final mano-a-mano battle, Kirk - a human - proves he still has a fighting spirit, despite being raised in the warm, safe, cozy environment provided by the Federation. He effectively disproves Krall's point, hence his statement.